# android preferences

Tags: android, preferences

i am using a listprefernce in my app and when a user makes a selection I would like to check it for errors, but when i set an onclicklistener it starts when i select the listpreference, not when i make my selection. is there a way to make it check the selection right after they make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer.  incase anyone else wants to know you need to use setOnPreferenceChangeListener and use the newValue object.